# Output of select-string has @{ in output

Tags: powershell

I am trying to get the services that are in auto mode but is not running and start them, except for few service which i want to ignore from script to check, is there way out to get the desired output with proper formatting as seen in image 2, because of the select-string output my script if not able to take service.name as variable.
i am using below command

```
Get-CimInstance win32_service -Filter "startmode = 'auto' AND state != 'running' "  | select name, startname, exitcode | Select-String   "gupdate|RemoteRegistry"  -NotMatch
```

[output that i am getting is](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VmWR8.jpg)

[but the desired output is](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wILJZ.png)

below is my script

```
    $Services = Get-CimInstance win32_service -Filter "startmode = 'auto' AND state != 'running' "  | select name, startname, exitcode | Select-String  -Pattern "gupdate|RemoteRegistry" -NotMatch
$ServicesRunning = Get-CimInstance win32_service -Filter "state = 'running'"
if ([string]::IsNullOrEmpty($Services)){
    Write-Output "OK: All services running | ServicesRunning=$($ServicesRunning.Count);0;0;0;0"
    $host.SetShouldExit(0)
}
else{
    $ServicesStopped=""
    ForEach ($Service in $Services){
        Start-Service @($Service.Name) -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | Out-Null  
        if ($(Get-Service -Name ($Service.Name)).Status -eq "running"){
            $ServicesStopped += "($Service.Name)(Started manually),"
            If ($ExitCode -eq 0){
                $ExitCode = 1
            }
        }
        Else{
            $ServicesStopped += "$($Service.Name)(Stopped),"
            $ExitCode = 2
        }
    }
    If ($ExitCode -eq 2){
        Write-Output "CRITICAL: Service(s) stopped: $($ServicesStopped.TrimEnd(",")) | ServicesRunning=$($ServicesRunning.Count);0;0;0;0"
        $host.SetShouldExit(2)
    }
    Else{
        Write-Output "WARNING: Service(s) stopped: $($ServicesStopped.TrimEnd(",")) | ServicesRunning=$($ServicesRunning.Count);0;0;0;0"
        $host.SetShouldExit(1)
    }
}
```

Comment: `Get-CimInstance win32_service -Filter "name!='gupdate' AND name!='RemoteRegistry' AND startmode='auto' AND state!='running' "  | select name, startname, exitcode`

Comment: thanks  Ansgar Wiechers this solved by issue... you are rocking man..!!!

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers post an answer :)

Answer (score 0):

`Select-String` expects a string or list of strings as input. `Select-Object` produces a list of custom objects. Plugging the latter into the former causes the output of the latter to be converted to a string. Which is obviously not what you want. And it's not needed anyway, since you can do all the filtering directly the the `Get-CimInstance` parameter `-Filter`:

```
$fltr = "name!='gupdate' AND name!='RemoteRegistry'" + 
        " AND startmode='auto' AND state!='running'"

Get-CimInstance Win32_Service -Filter $fltr |
    Select-Object Name, StartName, ExitCode
```